# Нужно ли ставить тире перед словом "это"?

Tags: пунктуация

Её поддержала вся страна. Некоторые собирают деньги, другие пишут письма () для публичного человека () это не мало.

Нужно ли здесь тире? Если да, то где?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Не вижу никаких причин ставить тире перед словом "это". "Это немало для публичного человека" - обычное предложение.

(2) А вот после слова "письма" знак препинания необходим, потому что далее следует новое предложение. Можно просто поставить точку. Можно поставить тире, которое я бы обосновал, сославшись на [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire): *"§ 167. Тире ставится перед обобщающим словом, стоящим после перечисления, например: 
Надежду и пловца – все море поглотило."*

По-моему, "некоторые собирают деньги" и "другие пишут письма"  — перечисление, а "это" — обобщающее слово.

Можно сослаться и на другое правило (см. там же на Грамоте): "*§ 171. Тире ставится между предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если второе предложение заключает в себе результат или вывод из того, о чем говорится в первом, например: Хвалы приманчивы – как их не пожелать? (Крылов) Солнце взошло – начинается день."*

(3) "Немало" здесь употреблено, скорее всего, в смысле "много", поэтому я бы писал слитно.

**Некоторые собирают деньги, другие пишут письма — для публичного человека это немало.**

Comment: Ну зачем на какую-то "грамоту" ссылаться, если это Правила 56 г. На Стек Вы не будете ссылаться, если вдруг захотите Пушкина процитировать по приведенной у нас цитате?

Answer (score 1):

Её поддержала вся страна. (1) Некоторые собирают деньги, (2) другие пишут письма — (3) для публичного человека  это не мало.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, предложение 3 является выводом из предложений 1 и 2, поэтому ставится тире. Перед местоимением "это" нет тире, это не связка, указательное местоимение является подлежащим в предложении (3).

Возможны обе формы: не мало и немало (почти много), разные количественные оценки.

Comment: Насчет "это немало" и  "это не мало" вы правы. В Нацкорпусе встречаются оба варианта. Но слитное написание преобладает (136 против 24) .

Comment: Я специально написал раздельно,чтобы нельзя было трактовать "это немало" как "этого много",хотя не знаю - корректно ли такое написание/произношение.